# Using AWS or Azure, what to do about emails?

Tags: email, amazon, amazon-ec2, azure

I'm coming from a background of paying a hosting company X amount per month for a server. This server comes with IIS, WebsitePanel and Smartermail all bundled together. When I create a new domain using WebsitePanel it automatically creates my email account. All I then need to do is configure my DNS to point to the server.

I've decided that it is more cost efficient to move to AWS / Azure.

Has anyone come from a similar background and moved onto a cloud system? I'd be interested to know what you did regarding emails. So far, these are the suggestions I've seen:

- Use Google Apps for each domain
- Use something like Elastic Email to sent out emails
- Launch a new instance and host an email server on that

The first option seems like quite a lot of manual configuration, the second one works good with outgoing emails but what about receiving? Option 3 would make it less cost effective.

What is your experience?

Comment: I realise this an old post, but wonder how you moved forward with this issue? Any advice you could pass on would be greatly appreciated. Also, rather than launching a new instance, why not run your email server and IIS on the same box? It wouldn't cost that much more to

Comment: Hi Phill, I currently use Mandrill for SMTP / automated emails from the website and have settled on using Google Apps for user based email where send and receive is required.

Answer (score 2):

I use SendGrid.com with Azure. There is an API, but the easiest way is to just use their SMTP server. Pricing is very reasonable, a couple of dollars for thousands of emails per month.

I previously used Google Apps but there are limitations, like 1000 emails per days, which could be a problem if you have to send in bulk.

Regarding receiving emails, I use Google Apps for that. Anyone that replies to a system email will be sent to my Google Apps domain. Or more often, every email sent via Sendgrid will have a reply-to set by the application user (this is a SAAS app) where the email is sent to.